# How do I save list to text file?

Tags: c#, file

At the moment I have this and it saves `(System.Collections.Generic.List'1[System.String])` but I want it to save the text in the string.

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(lblName.Text + ".txt");
    tw.WriteLine(save);
    tw.Close();
}
```

Comment: `File.WriteAllLines($"{lblName.Text}.txt", myListToSave);`

Comment: You want to save list of strings? You can save one string per line for example. Or use JSON.

Comment: Since `save` is apparently a collections of strings, you could use [File.WriteAllLines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealllines) and pass this collection to the method. It'll do everything on its own.

Answer (score 2):

You don't want `Stream`s in simple cases, but [File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file?view=netcore-3.1) class only:

To save a `List<string>`:

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    File.WriteAllLines($"{lblName.Text}.txt", myListToSave);
}
```

Or, if you want appending new lines to an existing file:

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    File.AppendAllLines($"{lblName.Text}.txt", myListToSave);
}
```

To save a `string`:

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    File.WriteAllText($"{lblName.Text}.txt", myStringToSave);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, `tw.WriteLine(save)` calls `save.ToString()` to convert your object to a string. What you actually want is the content of the List. You could do something like this:

```
 static async void WriteCharacters()
 {
    using (StreamWriter writer = File.CreateText(lblName.Text + ".txt"))
    {
       foreach(string s in save)
       {
           await writer.WriteLineAsync(s);
       }
    }
}
```

Couple of details:

- This method is async. It's a best practice to use async for Input/Output operations. When calling this method, make sure to use `await`.
- StreamWriter implements `IDisposable` which means you can use it in a `using { }` statement. That way, you can be certain the file always gets closed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(lblName.Text + ".txt");
    foreach (String save in Lists.your_list)
      tw.WriteLine(s);
    tw.Close();
}
```